# Exception Occured While Building Android project

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

OS: Linux mint 14.

Following error occurs when I try to run my project.

```
[TRACE] Writing out AndroidManifest.xml
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "/home/aqeel/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.0.GA/android/builder.py", line 2528, in <module>
[ERROR]     builder.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host, profiler_host=profiler_host)
[ERROR]   File "/home/aqeel/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.0.GA/android/builder.py", line 2264, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     self.manifest_changed = self.generate_android_manifest(compiler)
[ERROR]   File "/home/aqeel/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.0.GA/android/builder.py", line 1404, in generate_android_manifest
[ERROR]     '-I', self.android_jar], warning_regex=r'skipping')
[ERROR]   File "/home/aqeel/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.0.GA/android/run.py", line 38, in run
[ERROR]     print "[DEBUG] %s" % subprocess.list2cmdline(args_to_log)
[ERROR]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 587, in list2cmdline
[ERROR]     needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
[ERROR] TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
[ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1
[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 1m 7s 999ms
```

Comment: which OS you are using ? MAC ?

Comment: @Lucifer I am using Linux Mint 14.

Comment: Did you tried restarting your system? This occurs often in Titanium when doing updates.

Comment: @Oam yes, I restarted the system several times. But to no avail.

Comment: This looks like Titanium SDK specific issue. You may want to remove `android` tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try downgrade Android SDK tools (maybe also platform-tool and build tools) rev22 to rev21.
same problem occurred my mac(OSX 10.8.3). I restored Android SDK directory from timemachine.

Comment: I had already figured out that the problem was due to titanium's incompatibility with latest android sdk. I manually changed some 4, or 5 lines in androidsdk.py file. But this solution is cleaner, and easier, and reliable. Thanks.

Comment: **NOTE:** Also update ANDROID_SDK environment variable, in case you have placed old android sdk in separate folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this issue on a new install of Titanium Studio, make sure that in your app's "tiapp.xml", under build properties, "Titanium SDK" is set to 3.1.3GA (or, for future readers, whatever the latest version is).